# How to complete the form with last id from Mysql on submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, autofill

I am making an order form witch will fill data in 2 mysql tables.
order and order_details
both table contains order_number column. 
I have created a 3th table named order_num that contains order_numbers.
My question is:
How can I fill the order_number in order and order_details with last order_numbers from order_num table +1 when user click on Submit ?
NB order_details has many rows per order and all rows should have same order_number for each order. (there is a relation of 1 to many between order and order_details)

Here is what has been done
DB connect

```
connect.php
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user2';
$dbpass = 'password';
$dbname = 'db3';

$con=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>


entryform.php

<?php

  <form action="../action/custompcorder.php/" method="post">
<p>Order number: <input type="text" name="order_number"/> part_id: <input     type="text" name="part_id"/> quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity"/></p> 
<p>Order number: <input type="text" name="order_number2"/> part_id: <input  type="text" name="part_id2"/> quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity2"/></p>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>

?>



custompcorder.php

<?php
include_once '../action/connect.php';

$sql="INSERT INTO order_details (order_number, part_id, quantity,)
VALUES
('$_POST[order_number]','$_POST[part_id]','$_POST[quantity]'),
('$_POST[order_number2]','$_POST[part_id2]','$_POST[quantity2]')";



$sql="INSERT INTO order (order_number)
VALUES
('$_POST[order_number2]')";


?>

Thank you for your help.
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$last_order_id = mysql_insert_id();
```